# PHP image uploads: how do I protect against images containning code?

Tags: php, file-upload

From what I understand, images (jpeg, gif, etc.) might contain valid PHP/Python/Perl etc. code. So - anyone can create file that will be valid jpeg at the same time can be executed by PHP interpreter ([here is a description](http://blog.insicdesigns.com/2009/01/secure-file-upload-in-php-web-applications/)).

So, I was wondering - is there a way to strip malicious code from images? would recoding images with GD or ImageMagick work?

Comment: It's probably better to simply prevent the execution of PHP, etc. in directories where user-uploaded files exist.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. i'm doing that and more already. But it still seems helpful not to have any malicious code whatsoever on the server, just in case if later there will be server switch/upgrade or someone else managing the server who is unaware of this.

Answer (score 4):

Actual images will not contain code.  But there's nothing stopping someone from trying to get an "image" file uploaded, and then try and get it to execute.

Your interpreters (Perl, PHP, whatever) should be set up so that they only execute certain file types (i.e. .php or .php5).  There's no reason Perl or PHP should be parsing image files.

Just use the following common sense to protect yourself:

1)  Verify the mime type of the document
2)  Enforce policies that only allow uploading files of a certain extension
3)  Don't accept filenames at face value.  Generate your own internal file name and use a database table to keep the mapping.
4)  If you're truly paranoid, find some code to check that the byte signatures are valid for the given file type upload.

Comment: 1)set by client side -easily spoofed 2)Even if we know exactly what file extensions are interpreted by PHP now, we have no guarantee that this does not change at some point in the future, when some other application is installed on the web server. By that time everybody is bound to forget that the security of our server depends on this setting.  3) Not good for SEO, also - there will be way higher DB load, also - what if I need an image url to send in email or something 4) I do use file_info with magic database, so I am paranoid I guess, but byte headers can still be easily spoofed.

Comment: Well, to retort, 1) I'm not talking about validating the mime type coming from the client side, but rather using a library to analyze the actual file; 2) PHP should never be parsing image files to execute them as PHP code; 3) Agreed on this part, but most large sites that allow image uploads do the same thing; if you need a link, then give the user a link to the actual file; you don't have to use their filename (and indeed shouldn't in case of collisions); and wrt to #4, you should always perform your analysis server-side on the actual file, where it cannot be spoofed.

Comment: well. When user uploads a file  - browser (or swf/java plugin) submits mime information along based on a file. This is what shows up in $_FILES["File"]["type"] and can be spoofed. If you validate mime type on server-side - this is usually done by using magic database and finfo_file function - this is a bit more reliable, but still nobody prevents attacker from adding incorrect byte header prior to uploading a file.   So - in retrospect - if you mean that your 1) should be done server -side - then your 1) and 4) are the same things.

Comment: @Andre: that's absolutely true that MIME type and even magic bytes can be spoofed.  The question is whether or not that is a threat vector for an attack.  There is no 100% certain way to limit what someone will upload if you allow user-uploaded content.  But given standard server-hardening practices, you should not be executing ANY user uploaded content, and you should not be allowing users to upload php/perl/executable files.  There's no way to completely prevent it, unless you personally inspect each file uploaded, which isn't practical.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure your webserver not to allow your image filename extensions to get interpreted by PHP. As showed on the page linked in the question, images can contain PHP code. Always check the filename extension against a whitelist:

```
<?php  
$whitelist = '/\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)$/i'; 
if (!preg_match($whitelist, $_FILES['userfile']['name'])) {  
    echo "Bad filename extension.";  
    exit;  
}
$uploaddir = 'uploads/';  
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);  
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {  
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.";  
} else {  
    echo "File uploading failed.";  
}  
?>
```

Comment: the extension in the uploaded file name may be easily circumvented, better use `getimagesize()` function which return the true mime-type of the image, based on actual file contents.

Comment: recommended method of detecting mime type is by using PHP's finfo function. But this is still something that attacker can change.