# PHP security. Check uploaded files are valid

Tags: php, security, upload

I'm building a web app which will allow users to upload audio files.

In light of bitcointalk going down today and the speculation that it may have been compromised by the attacker uploading a piece of malicious code disguised as an avatar image, what is the best way to check an uploaded file on the server to ensure it is in fact a valid audio file? Is there a library I should be using or a function built into PHP?

Comment: [here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101753/php-image-uploads-how-do-i-protect-against-images-containning-code) an old SO article

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't matter if it's a valid audio file. You can make ‘chameleon’ files that are valid interpreted as two filetypes at the same time.

Uploaded files should:

- be stored on the filesystem using a filename that is not sourced from user input, in a directory where the webserver is set up only to serve static files and not execute code. (Avoids a range of code-injection and directory-traversal attacks; sounds like this was bitcointalk's problem, if they had a .php file in the avatars directory.)
- be served only from a different hostname (preferably, different domain name) than the main site. (Defeats cross-site-scripting attacks in uploaded content, as compromising the throwaway uploads domain gains nothing.)

Validating the contents of the file is something you will likely want to do to make your app nice to use, but you shouldn't be relying on it to protect you from malicious uploads.